# Accelerate to Max velocity, then decelerate to known velocity

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have an object traveling at a known velocity (Vi).  It then accelerates (known A) to a known maximum velocity (Vmax), then decelerates (-A) to another known velocity (Vf).  The total distance traveled is also known (Xf-Xi).  I'm looking for an equation that will give me total elapsed time (t) when Xi, Xf, Vi, Vmax, Vf, and A are all known quantities.  It also needs to take into account that Vmax may not be attained if the (Xf-Xi) is too small.

Comment: Does it travel any distance at $V_i$ before accelerating? Does it travel any distance after decelerating to $V_f$? If the answer to both questions is No, then you can easily calculate the time as $\frac{V_{max}-V_i}{A}+\frac{V_{max}-V_f}{A}$. If the answer to both is Yes, then the total time is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

The three important formulas in kinematics are
$$ d=v_it + \frac12at^2$$
$$a=\frac{v_f-v_i}t$$
$$v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2ad$$
where

$d =$ travelled distance

$v_i =$ initial velocity

$v_f =$ final velocity

$a =$ acceleration

$t =$ elapsed time

Can you proceed?